# howto get the selectionChanged signal

Tags: plugins, pyqt, qgis

Hi I am developing a plugin for Qgis in python, I need to connect the sselectionChanged signal emitted when a feature of the layer is selected, I could not find any examples on internet, here is what I have done as far

```
QObject.connect(self.iface.mapCanvas(),SIGNAL("selectionChanged(QgsMapLayer)"), self.test)
```

on the log of qgis  I get this warning

```
Warning: Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is to create a signal every time you select a layer:

```
def initGui(self):
    # ... your other code here
    self.handler = None
    self.selected_layer = None
    QObject.connect(self.iface,SIGNAL("currentLayerChanged(QgsMapLayer *)") ,self.layerChanged)

def layerChanged(self, layer):
    if self.handler:
        QObject.disconnect(self.selected_layer, SIGNAL("selectionChanged()"),self.select_changed)
        self.handler = False
        self.selected_layer = None
    if layer is not None:
        if layer.isValid():
            QObject.connect(layer,SIGNAL("selectionChanged()"),self.select_changed)
            self.selected_layer = layer

def select_changed(self):
   # whatever
   pass
```

edit: disconnect(wrong layer) fixed